# TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: javascript, string, object, instantiation, typeerror

In the following code, `TypeError: string is not a function` on line 30 `var myColour = new colour(255,255,255);` is thrown. Can anyone see what is wrong with the code. Many thanks.

```
var bodies = [];
var orbits = [];
var colours = [
    new colour(45, 45, 45),
    new colour(255, 0, 0),
    new colour(0, 157, 255),
    new colour(77, 250, 81),
    new colour(255, 247, 0)
];

function colour(red, green, blue)
{
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
};

window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    for (var colour in colours){
        console.log(colour.red);
        console.log(colour.green);
        console.log(colour.blue);
    };
    var myColour = new colour(255,255,255);
    console.log(myColour.red);
    console.log(myColour.green);
    console.log(myColour.blue);
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a local variable called `colour` in the `for...in` loop, and that is not a function. Change that variable to something other than the constructor function, like `c` and it'll work fine. Your code, corrected:

```
var bodies = [];
var orbits = [];
var colours = [
    new colour(45, 45, 45),
    new colour(255, 0, 0),
    new colour(0, 157, 255),
    new colour(77, 250, 81),
    new colour(255, 247, 0)
];

function colour(red, green, blue)
{
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
};

window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    for (var c in colours){
        console.log(c.red);
        console.log(c.green);
        console.log(c.blue);
    };
    var myColour = new colour(255,255,255);
    console.log(myColour.red);
    console.log(myColour.green);
    console.log(myColour.blue);
};​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RUBT7/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Though I have noticed another problem. I get 'undifined' values when looping through the colours array. Any ideas why? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nate Pretty sure that it's because you're using a `for...in` loop. Use an ordinary `for` loop or a `forEach` on the array, and it works fine. I've used a `forEach` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RUBT7/2/)

Comment: You are spot on. Also changing `c.red` to `colours[c].red` worked. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Local variable `colour` defined in `for (var colour in colours)` will be *[hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)* to the beginning of the `onload` function, so it will hide the global function `colour`. Changing the latter to `Colour` will solve your problem. Besides, it's good convention to capitalize the name of a function which serves as a `Class` name.

Comment: Thank you. Good tip on capitalising the name of a 'class' function